# WebBrowser-Control (WPF or Windows-Forms) can't display .SVG files contained in web-pages

Tags: wpf, winforms, svg, browser, html

My Forms / WPF application has to interact with an external ASP.Net application. In particular, it has to "consult" the external application that is nothing more than a catalog. I would like to use a WebBrowser control (it doesn't matter whether Win-Forms or WPF), to have more "integration" between the two applications. Then I wouldn't like to use a real browser.

But, when a web-page in the ASP.Net application contains a .SVG file, the WebBrowser control (both: WPF and Win-Forms) can't display the image, and, in its place, it leave an empty box.

The best should be to use a WebBrowser control, but we also evaluate an alternative third-party control, also not free. For example, I thought to be close to the solution with AB4D - ReaderSVG:

http://www.wpf-graphics.com/ReaderSvg.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ef9c3aca-427e-4445-9918-1fdc9f879f51

But unfortunately not: this component allows you to view a file .SVG and export it to another format, but when the file is contained in a web-page there is no way to see it.

Do you think I can solve the problem?
Thank you!
Pileggi

Comment: I have had the best results working with the Forms WebBrowser control. It seems to be easier to integrate with the actual application if you need that. Can you post some code so there is something to troubleshoot?

Comment: @Randy Thanks for your interest but now I'm in test then the only code I have written is WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("myurl"))

Comment: Do you have Internet Explorer 9 installed in the computer where you are making these tests? I believe IE9 is the first version to support SVG.

Comment: @Murven Thanks you. Yes, I  have IE9. With IE9 I see all the svg that in the WebBrowser I can't see. For example if I try to display this page http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_polygon3 with IE I see the star, with the webbrowser not.

Comment: @pileggi I just tried the sample URL in IE9 in my computer and I do not see the star. I do see the star in Chrome, though, so I think even IE9 may have troubles with SVG at this point. I have IE version 9.0.8112.16421. Which version of IE are you using where you can see the star?

Comment: @Murven Sorry, I can answer your question with precision only when I'll return to my office. I think it's the last version of IE: 9.0.8112.16421. Yes, I think IE and SVG are quite enemies, have you got some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't poperly a solution, it's a work-around: I integrate in a .NET the [Gecko](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) navigation component, and following this [article](http://winform-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/embeding-firefox-brower-gecko-engine-in.html), my .NET application can show, with hits GeckoWebBrowser, web-pages with .SVG files inside :-)

Pileggi

Answer (score 14):

you should just add this to `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you!!! But how can I interact with an external asp.net application adding the meta you suggest me? I don't know how can I release your suggestion

Comment: Sorry, my english is very poor. I have said: "I don't know how can I RELEASE your suggestion", I have wanted to say: "I don't know how can I IMPLEMENT your suggestion". I hope you have understood the meaning of the words and you will continue to help me :-)

Comment: `content="IE=Edge; "` will also work -- it will force the web browser control to simulate the latest installed version of IE.  (I am not sure whether the semi-colon and/or trailing space are required, but every time I've seen this workaround referenced, both are included.)